# thread exit but still hold mutex

Tags: linux, multithreading, mutex, deadlock

A thread which hold mutex died. Another thread will deadlock when it calls "pthread_mutex_lock", although I use "PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK" attribute.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *handler(void *)
{
    cout << "child thread" << endl;
    int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    cout << "child ret: " << ret << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, handler, NULL);

    sleep(2);
    cout << "father awake" << endl;

    int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    cout << "father ret: " << ret << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

**[LINUX ENVIRONMENT]:** Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: You didn't ask any question here -- but if your question is "how to handle this problem", the best solution is to make sure your thread releases any mutexes it might be holding, before exiting.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4424193/1230086) question appears to be asking the results of what your code does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are perhaps thinking of the *robust attribute* of mutexes ([`pthread_mutexattr_setrobust()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html)), rather than of the *errorcheck type* of mutex.  A robust mutex would have notified your main thread that the holder of the mutex's lock had terminated with EOWNERDEAD.

The PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK type, on the other hand, simply [guards against three kinds of errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html#tag_03_548_03):

1. attempting to recursively lock one's own locked mutex (not applicable here)
2. attempting to unlock a mutex locked by another thread (not applicable here)
3. attempting to unlock an unlocked mutex (not applicable here)

Answer (score 1):

This is a small example of using the [`pthread_mutexattr_setrobust`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html) call to allow for setting the `mutex` that was never unlocked back to a consistent state:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;

void dropped_thread(void)
{
    printf("Setting lock...\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("Lock set, now exiting without unlocking...\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t lock_getter;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST); 
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, &attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_create(&lock_getter, NULL, (void *) dropped_thread, NULL);
    sleep(2);

    printf("Inside main\n");
    printf("Attempting to acquire unlocked mutex?\n");

    pthread_mutex_consistent(&lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    printf("Successfully acquired lock!\n");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see by making the call to [`pthread_mutex_consistent`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_consistent.html) after setting the `mutex` robustness, its state is marked as consistent again.

Comment: You forget to initialize the mutex with `pthread_mutex_init`. Without that your code will result in deadlock.